# Everything your mouse touches is our kingdom

Tags: riddle

Being lucky underwhelms expectations;
   results expose desires,
   yearning, exhaling, longing, lamenting /
      overturned world.
Brazen lies upset everyone;
   gathering random entries, /
      everyone needed
   research erased delusions.

*What am I?*

Comment: Cat will take over the kingdom.

Comment: The words chosen are nonsense and in no way compose a riddle that directs a solver toward the desired solution.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Would you prefer a different tag other than riddle?

Comment: I think I would prefer the text to be a riddle whose words are chosen for more reason than "the first letter matches what I want".

Comment: While they are nonsense, they are technically sentences. But I know what you mean. Hindsight

Comment: How about that?

Comment: Hmmm.. Sounds a lot nicer, I don't mind that staying

Comment: Nothing on TV.  Best address dilemmas.  +1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you looking for

> Google
>
>  The colors Blue, Red, Yellow, blue, green, red clued in each line - thanks Techidiot and F1Krazy are the Google logo colors.
>
>  [image]
>   The title referring to the Google company's great involvement in web data.

Comment: While the color responses were interesting, this is what I was going for. *thumbs up*

Comment: Oh! Just got to it a few seconds back. :) +1

Comment: Wow, haven't seen that logo in years due to all the doodles, most of which don't maintain the colors...

Answer (score 10):

This seems almost too easy... you are

> The primary colours

If you

> Take the first letters of the first word on each line, they spell out "BLUE RED YELLOW BLUE GREEN RED". Blue-red-yellow are the primary colours in painting, blue-green-red are the primary colours on computer displays.

Everything your mouse touches is our kingdom

> Everything your mouse touches is made up of RGB colour values

Comment: Not the answer I am going for but almost there

Comment: I thought it was too easy...

Comment: You got the easy part, but even the final answer is pretty easy itself

Answer (score 7):

You are

> Colors or simply RGBY(Normal Colors or [Quattron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quattron) with a term called *SUBPIXELS* )

Reason

> One color is hidden in each line as first letter's.
>
>  **B**ig **l**lamas **u**nderwhelming **e**ars. - > BLUE
>  **R**andomly **e**ncountering **d**ragons. -> RED
>  **Y**elling, **e**ventually **l**ittle **l**izards **o**verwhelm **w**orlds. -> YELLOW
>  **B**ashing **l**egumes **u**ntil **e**rupting. -> BLUE
>  **G**arnish **r**adishes **e**xquisitely, **e**legantly **n**ever. -> GREEN
>  **R**owdy **e**nts **d**ance.  -> RED

An interesting concept

> The colors are in the form BRYBGR which as per the *Google* logo is it's color. [This article](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Googles-icon-colors-in-the-order-of-BRYBGR) states the reason as well.

Comment: Almost but not quite the answer I intended

Comment: @n_palum Might be display/graphics/pixels or any other related term I guess :-/

Comment: Perhaps there is a reason two colors are repeated?

Comment: @WeckarE. Continue.... and sorry it's not any related thing - pixels etc are not the answer I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

It's the ciiiiiiiircle of colooooooooooooour.

The acronyms on each line are colours and the title alludes to the Lion King.

Comment: Those repeated letters are really unnecessary

Comment: I guess. I was just having some fun with the lyrical nature of the song, but feel free to make it less playful in your edit. I'm not sure I follow your rationale for putting in a spoiler tag, either.